# How can I implement a MFC resource within a Win32 window?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I have two projects, an old project using the Win32 API that has an old toolbar using Win32 graphics and another one using MFC code with better graphics (I am creating a ribbon toolbar similar to the one that Microsoft Office uses). The MFC classes I use inherit from CDialogEx and CWinApp.

What I am trying to do is to place the ribbon toolbar in my Win32 window and replace the old one. I am already referencing the MFC project using it as a static library and can call the classes from my Win32 project but I can't get to show the new toolbar yet.

What do I need to do in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

It might be much easier to create the freamework with the MFC and move the old code into the new framework.

It is possible to create a MFC project without Doc/View architecture.

The MFC Ribbons will and can only live inside a CMFCFrameWnd that is part of a CWinAppEx... extracting just the ribbon code into a plain Win32 application should fail.

But there is also a [Win32 Ribbon Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316910%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). It might be much easier to implement this into your old Win32 project.

How to implement this is described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316924%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

In Codeproject you find a [sample](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119319/Windows-Ribbon-Framework-in-Win-C-Application) how to use it.

Comment: Thank you for answering! The thing is there are 1000's of lines of code in my Win32 project with some complicated GUI's and C++ dependencies so I would like to keep it the same. I already tried the tools you are suggesting before but I could not customize it completely (specifically the ribbon toolbar tabs, it was not possible to add icons, only text). So I am using a licenced product called Exontrol instead that lets you do that and also makes use of MFC. I basically just need to place a toolbar inside my existing Win32 window so I wonder if there's a way around.

Comment: See the Codeproject article. It is possible to add icons too!

Comment: Yes, it is possible to add icons within the tab groups. But I need to add icons to the tabs themselves besides the text too and that is not possible using the framework.